# Javascript array without quotes

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.
I'm using ZingChart to plot some data from a MySQL query.  I put the data into a PHP array, and then use:

```
var myData = <?php echo json_encode($combined); ?>;
```

to put it into a javascript array.
If I do:

```
document.write(myData[0]);
```

then it shows the correct value for that index.  When I try to use the array with the ZingChart's JSON, I see that it puts quotes around all the data, which for some reason it doesn't like.  If I manually remove the quotes using notepad, the data displays great, so I know it's just a matter of getting rid of these quotes somehow.

Here's how it looks, for example, when I view the source from the page:

```
var myData = [["1466766034467","71.191"],["1466766094482,71.1986"]];
```

I've tried many ways and spent many hours trying to get the data passed into JSON without the quotes, but I know just enough to be dangerous, so hopefully someone can guide me.

```
document.write(myData[1]);
```

will result: 1466766094482,71.1986

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($combined)`? The problem can likely be fixed by how you insert values into that variable. Somewhere the types are being set to a string.

Comment: have you tried mydata[0].toString?

Comment: `json_encode($combined, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running a reasonably current version of php you can add `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` to `json_encode()` options argument

```
json_encode($combined, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

See [json_encode docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Or in javascript iterate arrays and cast values to number using any variety of methods

```
myData.forEach(function(arr){
    arr[0] = +arr[0];
    arr[1] = +arr[1];
})
```

Comment: Note a nested forEach function may be needed to convert an array of arrays

Comment: @charlietfl your use of `+` to convert to numeric values is nice here since it applies to Integers and Floats equally.

Comment: @Traktor53 OP using 2D  chart data so seems like overkill here

Comment: Great, the numeric check did it.

Comment: So it worked, but the ZingChart JSON isn't liking the variable for the series data because it shows up as null.  I can copy the var's contents directly from the source off the page, and use that data and the chart shows up just fine.

Comment: Going to need to learn to use console.log instead of document.write for inspecting data. Note that one array you copied in question has quotes set differently than the other. Might be something wrong in php that creates array also if it doesn't look right in console

Comment: @Traktor53 @charlietfl if you're curious, I've posted a recursive forEach solution for numeric conversion of JS Arrays.  Of course, formatting data correctly at the start is preferable to manipulation after the fact, so `json_encode` better solves the problem at hand here.

Comment: Resolved this by going back to the PHP/MySQL level.  Your comment about the strings made me think.  Fixed by doing this:
    $time = $row[Time];
    $value = $row[Value];
    settype($time, "integer");
    settype($value, "float");

@charlietfl Thanks for the tip.  I will definitely use that.  I'm still way too green with this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the `String` types into `Int` and `Float`.  For your 2-item arrays, the following works with the `map` function:

```
myData.map(function(x){ return [parseInt(x[0]),parseFloat(x[1]) });

// or in ES6 notation
myData.map( x => [parseInt(x[0]),parseFloat(x[1])] );
```

---

### General Solution

Inspired by @charlietfl's solution, here's a generic function `parseNumeric` for converting all numeric data within an array. It will recurse through any nested arrays it finds.

```
var myData = [["1466766034467","71.191"],["1466766094482","71.1986"]];

// Convert data to numeric, including recursion within nested arrays
// Usage parseNumeric( myData );
function parseNumeric(x,y,z) {
  if( Object.prototype.toString.call( x ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    x.forEach(function(c,i,a){numConvert(c,i,a)});
  } else if ( typeof z != 'undefined' ) {
    z[y] = +x
  }
}

parseNumeric( myData );

// => [[1466766034467,71.191],[1466766094482,71.1986]];
```

Comment: I tried both of these directly after the myData declaration, and I still get the quotes around data (timestamp and value, respectively).

Comment: The snippets above don't mutate the source array, so you'd want to store the output in another var, send it somewhere, or overwrite myData: `myData = myData.map(...)`